# Android crash on build

Tags: android

I don't even know where to start with this error. Is there error in ACRA???

```
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/acra/ACRA$1;
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:703)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:577)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$7.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1133)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Dx 1 error; aborting
 [2012-11-11 18:01:57 - phca] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are adding two classes with the same name or two times the same class. Check your project properties, on Java Build Path and check if you happen to have included the same source twice.

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty much it. I had updated to the newest version of ACRA, and I forgot to delete the old one. How I missed that, I don't know.